# Duplicate Android User

Tags: multi-user

Since year dot I've always used one Android profile for home and work, with both work and email accounts added to Gmail, and social media logged in as work. Since it's my own business, it's difficult to ignore new notifications, or not reply to messages and emails, in an attempt to keep everyone happy and not waiting on a reply! Things need to change though, so I want to start using User profiles on Android.

My question is, is there any way of duplicating my current User to a new User, rather than starting from blank? This way, all settings, logins, installs etc are copied across. I'm looking for either an app do to the work, or even via adb.

Thanks!